# XSLT how sort only numeric values within a string node of XML document

Tags: javascript, css, xml, xslt

I have an app that generates an xml document with css formatting in the nodes to decorate the values.  I programmatically build and apply an XSLT document to the xml and want to sort it only by the numbers.  I'm processing the xml and xslt docs in JavaScript and then displaying the result as a report. The node values look like:

```
<span class="g">96%</span>
<span class="r">56.5%</span>
```

How can I sort the values and ignore any of the surrounding text?

Edit: Translate sounds like something that would work but I'm not sure how to apply it. I have n number of headers that are clickable.  When clicked, the document is modified and a new <xsl:sort field added with the title of the header that was clicked.

```
<th id="hdr6" <a href="#" onClick="sortXML(6,&quot;Collections_502&quot;,false)">Collections 502</a></th>
... later in the doc...
<xsl:for-each select="records/record">
<xsl:sort select="Collections_502/@value" order="ascending"/>
```

So, I'm not sure where to put the translate.  Would it look something like:

```
<xsl:sort select="translate('Collections_502/@value','0123456789','')" order="ascending"/>
```

EDIT 2:
There are multiple columns that can be clicked to sort. So, the xml looks something like:

```
<records>
<record id="12">
<person_first value="Bob"/>
<person_int value="15844"/>
<Collections_502 value="<span class='a'>100%</span>"/>
<Data_Security_494 value="<span class='a'>100%</span>"/>
<EBO_505 value="0"/>
<FDCPA_499 value="<span class='c'>50%</span>"/>
<General_Compliance_498 value="<span class='a'>100%</span>"/>
<HIPAA_500 value="<span class='a'>100%</span>"/>
<History_and_Ethics_497 value="<span class='a'>100%</span>"/>
<Human_Resources_495 value="<span class='b'>67%</span>"/>
<TCPA_404 value="<span class='b'>67%</span>"/>
</record>
<record id="13">
<person_first value="Erik"/>
<person_int value="14238"/>
<Collections_502 value="0"/>
<Data_Security_494 value="<span class='a'>100%</span>"/>
<EBO_505 value="0"/>
<FDCPA_499 value="<span class='a'>91%</span>"/>
<General_Compliance_498 value="<span class='a'>100%</span>"/>
<HIPAA_500 value="<span class='a'>100%</span>"/>
<History_and_Ethics_497 value="<span class='a'>100%</span>"/>
<Human_Resources_495 value="<span class='a'>100%</span>"/>
<TCPA_404 value="<span class='a'>100%</span>"/>
</record>
</records>
```

I got the following from an example on the web, "The inner translate( ) removes all characters of interest (e.g., numbers) to obtain a from string for the outer translate( ), which removes these non-numeric characters from the original string."

```
<xsl:for-each select="records/record">
<xsl:sort select="translate('HIPAA_500/@value', translate('HIPAA_500/@value', '0123456789', ''), '')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
```

It doesn't work.  No errors, just doesn't sort.

Comment: You can use the `translate()` function to remove the `%` (or any other) character.

Comment: Translate sounds like it might work.  I've edited the post with more detail.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the sort instruction could look like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="span">
    <xsl:sort select="translate(., '%', '')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    <!-- do something -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9cR

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know enough to write a good question.  Your answer looks right but I didn't give you enough information.  I've added more to the example so you can see the xml.  I didn't really understand thy the . in your example or why just the % was being removed.  The example I found didn't feel quite right but obviously I'm not sure what goes where.

Comment: The "XML" you have added is not a well-formed XML document and cannot be processed  by XSLT at all. You cannot have an unescaped `<` inside an attribute value. Without this, the instruction `<xsl:sort select="translate(HIPAA_500/@value, translate(HIPAA_500/@value, '0123456789', ''), '')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>` should work - assuming the attribute contains a single positive integer. Note the absence of quotes around the path.

Comment: Well... maybe the translate won't work with the <span tags, but it does recognize the span class, formats the values according to the class, and sorts using the xsl:sort in the original post.  That said, the problem with removing them is how to color the value's background, pad, etc.

Comment: Wow!  I just took the quotes off of the path and it works perfectly.